# Destruction of the universe by fire in the Ancient Greek canon?

Tags: greek, norse, roman

In Ovid's Metamorphosis, Zeus, thoroughly freaked out* by his encounter with Lycaon, [returns to Olympus, determined to rid the world of the evil race of men.](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0028%3Abook%3D1%3Acard%3D163)

A few lines later, Ovid relates that:

> "And now his thunder bolts
>   would Jove wide scatter, but he feared the flames,
>   unnumbered, (the) sacred ether might ignite
>   and burn the axle of the universe:
>   and he remembered in the scroll of fate,
>   there is a time appointed when the sea
>   and earth and Heavens shall melt, and fire destroy
>   the universe..." 
> <sub>Source: [Perseus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0028%3Abook%3D1%3Acard%3D253)</sub>

I can't recall a Greek source for this, aside from Plato:

> "...a destruction of the things on the earth by fierce fire, which recurs at long intervals." 
> <sub>Source: [Timeaus, 22d](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0180%3Atext%3DTim.%3Asection%3D22d)</sub>

But this very specifically references the destruction of earth ([γῆς](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=gh%3D&la=greek&can=gh%3D0)), and does not include heaven, per the oracle Zeus refers to in Ovid ("[ignibus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=ignibus&la=la&can=ignibus0&prior=ab&d=Perseus:text:1999.02.0029:book=1:card=253&i=1) [aether](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=aether&la=la&can=aether0&prior=ignibus&d=Perseus:text:1999.02.0029:book=1:card=253&i=1)" and so forth).

I find it interesting that such a prophecy appears only in the Latin canon, in Ovid, who was born a year after Julius Caesar was assassinated, by which I mean to say, during a period when there had been [documented contact with the Germanic tribes for well over a century.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanic_Wars)

**Q: Are there any Greek sources for the destruction of the Universe by fire?  Is it possible this prophecy derives from Germanic sources?**

---

*I say freaked out because Zeus is "[anxious](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=anxius&la=la&can=anxius0&prior=magis&d=Perseus:text:1999.02.0029:book=1:card=163&i=1#lexicon)" about his future sovereignty over the world, and goes on to suggest that nothing is safe if he himself can be "[ensnared](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=insidias&la=la&can=insidias0&prior=struxerit&d=Perseus:text:1999.02.0029:book=1:card=163&i=1)" by a psychopath such as Lycaon.*

Answer (score 6):

The Stoics had a doctrine about '[ekpyrosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ekpyrosis)' - a recurrent world conflagration. It was well in antiquity, [Chrysippus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrysippus) being credited for its original exposition. Details are given in David E. Hahm. *The Origins of Stoic Cosmology*, Ohio State University Press, 1977. or AA Long, *Stoics on world conflagration*, Southern journal of philosophy 23 (1985): 13-37 (and a rejoinder in a later issue 28.1 (1990): 149-58).

Actually the ekpyrosis was modelled as the beginning of a 'cosmic summer' in the [Great Year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Year): after very long interval all planets gather at the start of Cancer (the next important gathering is at the start of Capricorn and flood occurs).

Comment: Welcome to Mythology!  *(Props for bringing up the great year.)*